Automatic transmission and parking brake failure
I had my Nissan Quest brakes serviced. While there I mentioned the parking brake goes completely to the floor. I had to bring it back to get the parking brake adjusted. When they finished I put it in gear with the parking brake fully engaged and hit the gas. The van took off. I know any car will move but this seemed a bit excessive to me. I have 2 other cars that will hold briefly when I do the same thing. I asked the mechanic to make it tighter and he did. I don't love the feel but as long as I know how it works I'm OK. As I was getting ready to leave the manager came out and asked what I was trying to prove. I explained that I wanted to see more of a brief hold before it starts rolling. He preceded to tell me I don't know what I'm talking about and he's been working on cars for 30 years and no car works the way I described. He informed me that it was impossible for an automatic, front wheel drive to come out of gear. I suspect it is unlikely but "impossible" worries me. So, my question, have any of you mechanics ever known a vehicle with front wheel drive to come out of gear?
A test I performed just for my own curiosity. I parked the Quest on the hill in my driveway, fully engaged the parking brake and put the transmission in neutral. As I suspected, the van started rolling and got faster as it rolled down the hill. Second question, should a parking brake be able to hold the vehicle on an incline?
TIA for your comments.
sledge

What is the gradient of your driveway? Did the parking brake hold it before the work? Who suggested that the van was "coming out of gear"? Presumably, you mean that the parking brake should be tight enough that its resistance can be felt as you apply gas gently, before the engine moves the car. That is, feels a little different from when the brake wasn't applied.

Not sure what the gradient is but I have car and a toyota truck that both hold just fine. As for the gas yes I mean you push down a little and the vehicle should try to hold before breaking away. This van just rolls. The parking break would go to the floor before getting it adjusted. It is better, just not what I expect. I suggested coming out of gear scenario. I have a family member that wore a helmet for 3 years while his skull healed from a truck that came out of gear.

Please explain what you mean by "come out of gear." That means (to us) that the transmission shifts into neutral by itself, so pressing the gas pedal makes the engine rev but the car does not go faster. Please use other words to describe what you mean, because coming out of gear (to us) has nothing to do with the brakes.

You'll notice, I'm speaking specifically about the parking brake. So if the transmission comes out of gear (AKA, goes into neutral on it's own due to some flaw), the parking brake has everything to do with the situation. So let me ask my first question again. Have you ever experienced/heard of a front wheel drive vehicle with automatic transmission go into neutral on it's own? - sledge

Imo a properly adjusted and functional parking brake should hold the back wheels locked no matter what the incline of the hill is. Similarly if the parking brake is engaged and you put the vehicle in gear and hit the gas - the vehicle should not move unless it somehow manages to drag the back wheels along the ground.

"if the transmission comes out of gear (AKA, goes into neutral on it's own due to some flaw), the parking brake has everything to do with the situation. Sorry, I'm at a total loss to understand this theory. There is no connection whatsoever between the parking brake and the transmission. Putting a trans "in Park" engages a pawl inside the trans. The (separate) parking brake engages a friction surface for the rear wheels. No connection, different things. Never heard of an automatic trans popping into neutral on its own.
